# Resolve ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error on Chrome or any Browser

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

How to resolve this error that I get when trying to open a game window on come2play.com:

> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

I am able to view all other flash sites perfectly except this. Also, I am unable to see the page on any other browser like IE or Firefox.

Is internet connectivity the issue, or is it a site issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently I'm able to access [come2play.com](http://come2play.com). Seems like it was a site issue.
*(As you are not able to access the site in other browsers also, it can't be a browser issue.)*

To check whether a site is "Down" or "Its just your internet connection issue" you can use website such as:

- [Down for everyone or just me?](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com)
- [downornot.com](http://www.downornot.com)
- [thewebsiteisdown.com](http://www.thewebsiteisdown.com)

Such sites use servers located at different locations worldwide to Ping the requested website and find out if it's really, down for everyone or just you. 
I imagine **this wouldn't work perfectly** in a **multi-server situation**—like if some Google servers were up but not others. Still, a quick and easy way to see whether your problem is widespread.